# SQL Server function to get output zero or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck to get output from function that takes an input parameter and should return zero or not:

```
alter function dbo.ZERONOT(@input int)
returns varchar(30)
as
begin
    declare @result varchar(30)
    declare @result1 varchar(30)

    select @input = P_PRICE 
    from Product_ID

    if (@input > 0)
        set  @result = 'YES'
        return @result
    else
        set @result1 = 'NO'
        return @result1
    end
```

Comment: `@input` is a variable hold the value passed into the function, why you assign another value in? Also it will set a random value if you don't set the `WHERE` clause.Also whey you need two (2) `@result ` variables?

Comment: Hi sami . could you please help me in modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ZERONOT(@Input INT) --The input value stored here
-- The variable used to pass the value to the function and make some
-- operations based on it, do not change his value.
RETURNS VARCHAR(3)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(3);

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Products WHERE Product_ID = @Input) 
    --Or maybe the price because I don't think you have a table named Product_ID
        SET @Result = 'Yes'
    ELSE
        SET @Result = 'No';

    RETURN @Result
END
```

Don't forget to visit [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine)

Comment: ya price to check whether it is greater than zero or not .